# Thue-Morse Sequence riddle

Tags: sequences-and-series, bit-strings

The Thue-Morse sequence is constructed by replacing each instance of $0$ with the string $01$, and replacing $1$ with $10$. Equivalently, we can construct the sequence by successively appending the Boolean complement of the sequence obtained thus far. As an example, from  $0110$ we get $01101001$, then $0110100110010110$. The Thue-Morse sequence is the sequence which these processes converge to.

There are $8$ possible $3$-bit substrings, $000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111$. Two of these are not possible, which are they and why?

How many substrings of length $4$, $5$, or in general, $n$, are there? With proof! (Obviously $4$-strings or $5$-strings that have any of the not allowed $3$-strings from the first part cannot appear. I do not have a full proof of all the substrings that can appear.)

Comment: What's your "not rigorous" proof for the first part?

Comment: It is clearly $000$ and $111$ which never occur, but I'm not sure which key-fact you are referring to.

Comment: Fair enough.  When I learned it, it was in the context that the sequence was cube-free, but a quick trip to wiki informed me that this was not "key" in any real sense.  ^_^

Comment: For $n=4$ there are 16 bit strings. Thue Morse is cube free so there are only 10 substrings that appear in the sequence as 1111,1110,1000,0111,0001,0000 are not allowed. Since you can always invert a bit string, the number of disallowed strings is always even - maybe that will help with the proof. For $n=5$ there are 32 bit strings and via brute force I'm fairly sure there are 20 disallowed bitstrings leaving only 12 substrings - basically you have 18 disallowed substrings with triples and also 10101 and 01010 disallowed.

Comment: I've checked it for various $n$ and I get a sequence 2, 4, 6, 10, 12, 16, 20, 22, 24 which corresponds to https://oeis.org/A005942

 
a(n) = subword complexity (or factor complexity) of Thue-Morse sequence A010060 = number of factors of length n in A010060. See Allouche-Shallit (2003). - N. J. A. Sloane, Jul 10 2012